# A regular expression for a person's name that matches only the format "F. Lxxxxx"

Tags: regex, expression

Regular expressions are way over my head, so I ask for your assistance. I track data entry by volunteer name, and so I need to enforce the format of the name they type in my Google Form. I've chosen first initial (F above) followed by a period, a space, and their last name (Lxxxxx above). Their first initial and the first letter of their last name should be capital letters A thru Z. I have no need to handle international considerations. Allowing hyphenated last names would be a bonus. Thanks in advance.

A. Lincoln would pass. 
A.Lincoln would fail. 
A Lincoln would fail. 
ALincoln would fail.

Comment: It's a good question, but doesn't give us strict rules (which is needed for a proper regex). 1. What is the length of the last name (can it be one letter like `F. L`?) 2. If `-` are permitted, do two consecutive `--` cause it to fail (`F. La--x`)? 3. Similarly, is a last name permitted to contain more than one `-` (`F. La-a-x`)? 4. What about double spaces (say someone accidentally enters two spaces)? 5. Can names end with `-` (`F. Laxx-`)?

Comment: 1, Last name can be as short as 1 character. It can be as long as the field. 2. No consecutive hyphens. 3. One hyphen. 4. No double spaces. I'm doing a strict string match without parsing. 5. No trailing hyphen. It's meant for names like Lake-Smith.

Comment: Does `^[A-Z]\. [A-Z][a-z]*(?:-[a-z]+)?$` work for you? You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/NezGRK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce case, you could do this:

`/[A-Z]\. [A-Z][a-z\-]+/`

(Assuming no hyphens as the first letter)

If you don't care about the case, then:

`/[A-Za-z]\. [A-Za-z\-]+/`

(this one does allow hyphens as the first letter)

A great resource for learning about and testing regular expressions is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YjjanU/1).

Comment: Your second regex doesn't ensure uppercase variants are used for initials

Comment: Correct, that's why I said "If you don't care about the case ..."

Comment: The first option worked perfectly in a Google Forms text edit specification. Thank you! Now I won't need to manually edit mistypes.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression for your format would be

```
([A-Z])\. ([A-Z])\w+
```

There are a lot of tools online for generating and testing regex too.